# How to adjust Tkinter button height?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm sorry that my question might sounds stupid but I have read some wiki as well as questions posted on Stack Overflow, however, when I tried to adjust the button height, it seems only the frame size extends but the button remains same, please help me with this and here is my test code:

```
import tkinter

class Test:
  def __init__(self):
  self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
  self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
  self.button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text="Test", width=5, height=10)
  self.button.pack()
  self.button_frame.pack()

  tkinter.mainloop()

test = Test()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you actually want the button to be 10 lines high by 5 characters wide? Or, do you want the button to fill the section of the window that it in? Or both? Or something else?  Also, is this on a Mac or on another platform? You have very little control of the size of a button on a Mac.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley! Thank you for your reply but I mean to adjust the button size, either make it 10 * 5 or fill the frame, I am able to change the width, but height just doesn't work. I am work on a Mac, maybe it is the problem, do you have any idea how to change the default button height if I am using Mac?

Comment: You cannot change the button height in a mac. Why do you need such a large button? There are other widgets you can probably use.

Comment: Well, I am practicing with a simple calculator, it would be nice if the buttons would vertically aligned. Anyway, thank you very much for your help, and if possible, what would be your suggestion for my BIG button then?

Comment: You can use a label, and set a binding on `<1>`rather than use `command`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Bryan Oakley and finally I noticed that it is impossible to change the button height with Mac, and he suggested using label as alternative which is probably the best choice the solve the problem.

Thank you again for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify internal padding in the pack command:

```
self.button.pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10)
```